# Object and number trick

Tags: number-theory, game-theory

> You are telling your friends Adam and Steve a trick and here is how it
>   goes:
>
> Tell Adam to take out $3$ objects from his pocket which all the
>   objects have a different amount of letters. Lets say Adam picks keys,
>   watch, bag. Now ask Adam to think of one of the objects he picked.
>   (Lets say Adam picked watch). Now ask Adam to take the number of
>   letters in the object (which is $5$) and do the following, multiply
>   the number by $5$, add $3$ and then double the total. Now have steve
>   whisper in adam's hear a number from $1-9$, whatever number steve
>   whispered to adam must be added to adam's total.
>
> you are able to tell what object adam was thinking about and what
>   number steve told adam, how?

Like i said:

Lets say adam was thinking about a watch which has $5$ letters. Now:

$$2[(5 \times 5)+3]=56$$

Lets say Steve whispered $7$, then $56+7=63$

I did this a couple of more times with different numbers but wasnt able to see the pattern. does anyone else see it?

Comment: In the description of the problem you instruct us to multiply by $5$ but in the example you multiply by $3$.

Comment: yes you are right, i made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should help to write out algebraically what exactly is happening. Suppose that the number of letters for Adam's object is $x$. Adam will then quintuple it to get $5x$ and add three to get $5x+3$. He then doubles it to get $10x+6$. Then, another number $k$ is added to it to get $10x+6+k$. Can you see how to recover $x$ and $k$ from this? Try playing around with it and maybe making a table of the value of $10x+6+k$ depending on $x$ and $k$.

(More simpliy: Suppose you knew $10x+k$? Could you figure it out then? Try plugging suitable values for $x$ and $k$ into this and see a pattern)

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is the number of letters in Adam's word and Steve's number is $n$ then the number you get is $2(5x+3)+n=10x+6+n$.

To get Steve's number you subtract $6$ from the total and take the remainder from dividing by $10$. Subtracting that number from the total gives you $10x+6$ so you subtract $6$ from that number and divide by 10 to get the number of letters in Adam's word.